# Making SVGs scale responsively

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, responsive

I'm pulling my hair out trying to centre the SVG logo and get it to scale responsively. I want the SVG to scale according to screen width but have a maximum width of 800px. For lower screen resolutions it should scale down. I also need it to have 40px padding on both sides.

The background/body colour randomises each time you load the page or click on the logo.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <link href="http://static.tumblr.com/y3vtpdx/Lskoeb774/favicon.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
    <title>
        Accoutrements
    </title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="Accoutrements is a multidisciplinary studio specialising in art direction, design, photography and screen printing." name="description">
    <meta content="accoutrements, art direction, design, manchester, photography, screen printing, studio” name=">
    <meta content="index,follow" name="robot">
    <meta content="© 2017 Accoutrements All rights reserved." name="copyright">
    <meta content="Accoutrements" name="author">
    <style>

    body {font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
       font-size: 18px;
       font-weight: 400;
       -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
       }

    .about {
       position: fixed;
       right: 40px;
       bottom: 40px;
    }

       .shop {
       position: fixed;
       right: 40px;
       top: 40px;
    }

       .studio {
       position: fixed;
       left: 40px;
       top: 40px;
    }

           .mood {
       position: fixed;
       left: 40px;
       bottom: 40px;
    }

    a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }


    svg.logo
    {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 80%;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    }

    svg.logo:empty
    {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    @media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    svg.logo {
     max-width: 90%;
    }
    }

    @media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    svg.logo {
     max-height: 90%;
    }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="corner_link about">
        <a href="/about">About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="corner_link shop">
        <a href="/">Shop</a>
    </div>
    <div class="corner_link studio">
        <a href="/">Studio</a>
    </div>
    <div class="corner_link mood">
        <a href="/">Mood</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accoutrements">
        <svg class="logo" id="accoutrements" viewbox="0 0 800 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <title>
            Accoutrements
        </title>
        <path d="M32,160H24l-2,40H0L12,0H44L56,200H34ZM28,48l-4,88h8Z"></path>
        <path d="M494,0h30l4,100L532,0h30V200H540V88l-8,112h-8L516,88V200H494Z"></path>
        <path d="M650,0l8,112V0h20V200H652L644,74V200H622V0Z"></path>
        <polygon points="318 0 318 24 332 24 332 200 356 200 356 24 370 24 370 0 318 0"></polygon>
        <polygon points="686 0 686 24 700 24 700 200 724 200 724 24 738 24 738 0 686 0"></polygon>
        <polygon points="466 24 486 24 486 0 442 0 442 200 486 200 486 176 466 176 466 112 482 112 482 88 466 88 466 24"></polygon>
        <polygon points="594 24 614 24 614 0 570 0 570 200 614 200 614 176 594 176 594 112 610 112 610 88 594 88 594 24"></polygon>
        <path d="M118,90V28c0-8.13-1.94-14.87-6-20S101.87,0,92,0H88C78.13,0,72.05,2.87,68,8s-6,11.87-6,20V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V110H94v64a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0V90Z"></path>
        <path d="M182,90V28c0-8.13-1.94-14.87-6-20s-10.13-8-20-8h-4c-9.87,0-15.95,2.87-20,8s-6,11.87-6,20V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V110H158v64a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0V90Z"></path>
        <path d="M240,8c-4.05-5.13-10.13-8-20-8h-4c-9.87,0-15.95,2.87-20,8s-6,11.87-6,20V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V28C246,19.87,244.06,13.13,240,8ZM222,174a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0Z"></path>
        <path d="M286,0V174a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V0H254V172c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V0Z"></path>
        <path d="M434,76V20c0-16-7.16-20-16-20H378V200h24V112h4a4,4,0,0,1,4,4v84h24V108c0-6-2-14-10-14C434,94,434,81.52,434,76Zm-24,8a4,4,0,0,1-4,4h-4V22h4a4,4,0,0,1,4,4Z"></path>
        <path d="M794,8c-4.05-5.13-10.13-8-20-8h-4c-9.87,0-15.95,2.87-20,8s-6,11.87-6,20V74c0,6.19.24,9.49,2,14s5.77,9.94,10,14l10,10c1.94,1.95,10,8,10,14v48a4,4,0,0,1-8,0V118H744v54c0,8.13,1.94,14.87,6,20s10.13,8,20,8h4c9.87,0,15.95-2.87,20-8s6-11.87,6-20V126c0-6.9-.06-11.76-2-16s-5.07-7.4-10-12c0,0-6.43-6.07-12-12-4.25-4.53-8-8.61-8-12V26a4,4,0,0,1,8,0V82h24V28C800,19.87,798.06,13.13,794,8Z"></path></svg> 
        <script>
          var safeColors = ['00', '33', '66', '99', 'cc', 'ff'];
          var rand = function() {
              return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
          };
          var randomColor = function() {
              var r = safeColors[rand()];
              var g = safeColors[rand()];
              var b = safeColors[rand()];
              return "#" + r + g + b;
          };
          var color_1 = randomColor();
          var color_2 = randomColor();
          $(document).ready(function() {
              color_change();
              $('#accoutrements').click(function() {
                  color_change();
              });
          });
          function color_change() {
              color_1 = randomColor();
              color_2 = randomColor();
              $('.corner_link a').css('color', color_1);
              $('.accoutrements').css('fill', color_1);
              $('body').css('background', color_2);
              $('.corner_link a').hover(function(){ $(this).css('color',color_2).css('background-color',color_1); }, function(){ $(this).css('color',color_1).css('background-color','transparent'); });
          }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I **removed** the following media query, from your code, it worked absolutely as required. The logo was centered and responsive, scaling down as the width of the screen reduced.

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
   svg.logo {
     max-width: 90%;
   }
}
```

Now, from your question, I think that maybe you want to limit the size of the logo to 800px. That is once the logo reaches 800px width, it should remain 800px wide and then just align itself to the center.
If so, that can be achieved by the following media query.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  svg.logo {
    max-width: 800px;
    position: inherit; /* Removing position: absolute */
    margin-top: 10vh;  /* Equivalent to having top: 10% */
    /* The following lines will horizontally center the logo. */
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
}
```

The logo has max width set to 80%. So once the screen width is 1000px the logo becomes 800px wide. Hence for screen sizes from 1000px and above, we specify the max-width absolutely (not in percentage) to prevent it from growing. So once the screen is 1000px or more the logo size remains fixed and it remains centralized and at 10% from the top of the screen.

Try it out and see if it is what you want. Otherwise please clarify your question.
I am using Google Chrome 58 and used the dev tools to check responsiveness.

Comment: Thank you, that's worked. Is there anyway to make it so it's centred vertical as well as horizontally? Also is there a way 40px padding can be added to the left/right so it matches the padding of the four text links?

Comment: To vertically center the svg, you can use the following.
`top: 50% /* if position: absolute; or use margin-top: 50vh*/
transform: translateY(-50%);`

Also include the -webkit, -moz, -ms, and -o-transform for the same property to ensure cross browser functionality.

Comment: I do not understand why you need to add the paddings, exactly the logo fits fine without any padding. Can you please explain what you are looking for?
Using absolute positioning along with paddings seems to interfere with the responsiveness.

Comment: One thing you could do it, not use absolute positioning. And use the following CSS for your svg.
`svg.logo {
  max-width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50vh;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
 `.

This way the logo was responsive, horizontally and vertically centered and also had 40px padding on each side.

Comment: Glad to help. :)
Thank you for accepting the answer.